# Could I define entity type automatically?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, information-retrieval, text-analysis, information-extraction

I am trying to develop software to get suitable attributes for entities names depending on entity type.

For example if I have entities such doctor, nurse, employee , customer, patient , lecturer , donor, user, developer, designer, driver, passenger and technician, they all will have attributes such as name, sex, date of birth , email address, home address and telephone number because all of them are people.

Second example word such as university, college, hospital, hotel and supermarket can share attributes such as name, address and telephone number because all of them could be organization.

Are there any Natural Language Processing tools and software could help me to achieve my goal. 
I need to identify entity type as person or origination then I attached  suitable attributes according to the entity type?

I have looked at Name Entity Recognition (NER) tool such as Stanford Name Entity recognizer which can extract Entity such as Person, Location, Organization, Money, time, Date and Percent But it was not really useful.

I can do it by building my own gazetteer however I do not prefer to go to this option unless I failed to do it automatically.

Any helps, suggestions and ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are mainly interested in knowing if a given word can be mapped to a general category of Human, Organization, etc.

You should use [WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn), which provides a complete hierarchy of the general English lexicon. Try it a bit in the user interface to get of feel of how it works.

WordNet encodes relations between words. One of these relation is [hypernymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy), a fancy word that means a relation of general-to-particular.

Some examples:

- Vehicle is a hypernym of boat.
- Vehicle is a hypernem of car.
- Human is a hypernym of worker which is a hypernym of plumber.

Hyponymy is the inverse relation of hypernymy:

- Boat is a hyponym of vehicle.
- Car is a hyponym of vehicle.
- Plumber is a hyponym of worker, itself a hyponym of human.

**These relations are transitive**, so in my last example `plumber` is also a hyponym of `human`. This gives you the solution to your problem: any word that has human as hypernym should be mapped to Human and have people attributes.

There are libraries to access WordNet from [Java](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#Java) and [Python](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#Python), as well as from many other languages. [Here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) is the documentation for using WordNet with the NLTK Python module.

### A short example to determine if a word is hyponym of "human"

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

human = wn.synset('person.n.01')
hyponyms_of_human = set(x for x in human.closure(lambda s:s.hyponyms())
fireman = wn.synsets('fireman')
salad = wn.synsets('salad')
print(any(x in hyponyms_of_human for x in fireman))  # outputs True
print(any(x in hyponyms_of_human for x in salad))  # outputs False
```